# Serverside Crossfilter: replicate filterfunction. How to access a variable from the function closure

Tags: javascript, closures, dc.js, crossfilter

Right now am working on a project using crossfilter. Since the Data to work with can get really big, I'm trying to port the crossfilter on the serverside. (well in the end I'm hoping to be able to serve the groups and dimensions directly from mongodb).

The Charts are working so far but I'm having a problem with filtering multiple values of a chart. To clarify am "overwriting", or better said creating a dummy function for dc.js which queries a server with the given filters.

```
var markerClickedDimension = {
    filter: function(f){
        if(f){
            queryFilter["markerClickedDimension"]=f;
            refresh(queryFilter);
        }
    },
    filterAll: function(){

    },
    filterFunction: function(f){
        if(f){
            // get the filters
        }
    }
};

var markerClickedGroup = {
  all: function(){
  //filteredDate -> Groups returned from the server
  return filteredData["markerClickedGroup"].values;
 },
 order: function(){

 },
 top: function(){
 }
};
```

Running the debugger I noticed the array I need is under the functions scope closure. But I'm lost how to access it.

[image: function scope]

I'm kind of in a hurry with my thesis, so sorry if this is too broad of a question.

Comment: What does your function return? can't you return an object with b inside?

Comment: the functions im implementing are dummy functions for the dimension dc.js is using. the original "filterfunction(f)" is implemented inside crossfilter.js tried to get a picture what is happening there but im kind of lost. the function scope is initiated withing dc.js or crossfilter.js im not really sure.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should probably look at customizing the filterHandler instead of trying to model the crossfilter dimension.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#basemixinfilterhandler--function--basemixin

My reasoning is that you will not be able to shuttle functions across to the server, and you don't really want to parse the functions to find out what they do. Instead, look at the filter objects (and simple values) which are put in the filters array.

Disclaimer: I'm starting to write my own server-side crossfilter replacement, but I haven't done all of the research. Just my impression so far of the best place to intercept the filtering calls.

The community is waiting on a number of folks who have promised to publish their own solutions using mongodb, elasticsearch, etc.

Here is a rather long thread on this subject. There is a solution (which actually takes a different approach) in a post by Blair Nilsson on 9/9/14, with which a few people have reported success.
https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/dc-js-user-group/fkRoFHuqg4k/lqbuoNKBCQAJ

Comment: i honestly dont know whats the best way to implement it. i looked at [link](https://github.com/lastlegion/dc.js-server-side-crossfilter) and [link](https://github.com/ZJONSSON/crossfilter) to implement it. the first one is alright but filters after groups on the server which, to my knowledge does not make any sense. It works smoothly, only filteing multiple values on one chart does not atm. but ill have to implement a way to use mondrian(or some sort of real olap) anyways, since my data changes for users, and one crossfilter per user on the server does not seem to be too good of an idea ;)

Comment: Huh, I didn't know the first one, thanks. Looks like pretty much the same idea as the one I linked, just implemented differently. It generates a query based on the filters, and then it redraws when the results come back. I'm not sure what you mean by "filters after groups", looks like it's just reading results from an array. Putting crossfilter on the server does have the downside that you have to reset the filters every time, which loses a lot of the efficiency.

Comment: You want to set the queryfilter to the dinension not the group inside the dimensions filter function. At least thats what works for me